# Is it possible to group by column1, but display column2 in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax, ssas-tabular

I have a Fact **Revenue**, with 2 dimensions: **Customer** and **Category**.

I have the below data:

[image]

(In my pbix I have the below visual). There are just 1 or 2 customers that have changed category; so for that specific case, I see:

[image]

(This is correct, since the NewCategory has no revenue for the last year).

But, I don't want to see **Revenue LYTD** as blank; is there a way to display **Category**, but in fact do a group by **Customer**?... That way, I would be able to display:

[image]

Code is:

Revenue YTD:=CALCULATE (  [Revenue] ,  DATESYTD('Date'[Date],"31/05") )

Revenue LYTD:=CALCULATE ( [Revenue YTD] ,  SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]) )

Answer (score 1):

I don't think something like that is possible, because logically it doesn't really make much sense.

In your desired outcome how do you know that it will show NewCategory if you don't group by it or specify it in any way? In some flavors of SQL that allow you to do that, it will show you the first category it finds (which in your specific case is OldCategory, but essentially it will be random and based on the order of rows in the table).

I would suggest first creating a mapping table, in which every old category corresponds to the relevant new category. Then join this table to your fact table. Finally, use a new category from the mapping table to group the revenue in the fact table.